# Android linkify an address without displaying the full address

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm writing an app for a specific area where the user really doesn't need to see the full address.  I want to turn a textview into a map address link, but don't want to have to explicitly type the full address.

Pretty simple, I only want to display the address number and street name, but leave the city, state, and zip out.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  Here's a chunk of my code.

```
textView.setText(towedVehicle.getAddress());
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES);
```

Comment: Where are you getting the address from?  An internal object?  Or are you geocoding a location obtained from a provider?

Comment: The address is coming from an internal object, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little searching I was able to solve it pretty easily

```
Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=address+of+location")); 
startActivity(searchAddress);
```

I made the textview clickable and underlined it to look like a normal link.

```
SpannableString towedToAddress = new SpannableString(towedVehicle.getTowedToAddress());
            towedToAddress.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,towedToAddress.length(), 0);
            towedToAddress.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0x990000FF), 0, towedToAddress.length(), 0);
            textView.setText(towedToAddress);
            textView.setClickable(true);
```

Opens up in Google maps and works great.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using  `Transformfilters` in the `addLinks` method. For an example please check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).